# Sufficient and necessary conditions

Tags: logic, terminology

Is it correct to say that sufficiency and necessity of a condition is like saying "if and only if"?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent.

Comment: Yes it is.  $P\Rightarrow Q$ is '$P$ is sufficient for $Q$'.  And $Q\Rightarrow P$ is '$P$ is necessary for $Q$'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

My knowing the combination to open this vault is a **necessary condition** to my finding $1 million inside it.

I will find $1 million inside the vault **only if** I know the combination.

The presence of $1 million in the middle of the vault that I open every morning is a **sufficient condition** for my finding it, since it's so conspicuous.  I can't miss it.

I will find $1 million there **if** it is there.